# Xcode does not deploy or launch Apple Watch simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I change the scheme to Apple Watch and hit run, the watch simulator shows up but my app icon is not even seen on the home screen of watch.

I have been trying for days now. I tried **cleaning project, cleaning build folder, removing derived data, removing files in the watchOS DeviceSupport, restarting Xcode(9.2), restarting Apple Watch Simulator**

*(External Displays option does not shows Apple Watch Alternatives by the way)*

Can you help with the possibilities that might cause this issue?
What else should I try?

*Xcode does not launch my app on the watch simulator* :/ this is the summary of the issue.

Comment: Watch targets exist in your Xcode project?

Answer (score 1):

On the iOS(iPhone) simulator launch the Apple "Apple Watch" app (not your app) scroll all the way down to the buttom, down there your app should have a loading icon next to it, wait 20 minutes if the icon haven't shown up on the watch, restart your computer, with the option to relaunch all apps ticked to off, launch xcode, then try the above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When trying out my first watchOS app, I was seeing the same behaviour. I could not find the app's icon in the simulator. The following is what I did.

- I stopped the app in Xcode.
- Launched it again.
- This time I opened the main app in the iPhone simulator also.
- The icon for the app appeared in the watch simulator among other apps and the app launched.
- For ~10 seconds a loading indicator was shown.

I was able to continue debugging normally from then on.